# kubernetes restart all the pods using REST api

Tags: kubernetes

I need to update all the pods(rolling updates), with env variable changes

I am not using kubectl, but using REST api.

Right not i am deleting the service and pods; And then recreating both services and pods. (It usually take around minutes, and there is downtime). Wanted similar with rolling update, without downtime.

Comment: "Rolling Update" with "Downtime" is a strange question to ask. Seems you didn't understand the Rolling Update concept properly. We follow Rolling Update to maintain zero downtime. Please take a look at https://kubernetes.io/docs/tutorials/kubernetes-basics/update/update-intro/

Comment: yeah,, i meant without downtime.. updated the question.. thanks

Comment: Use Deployment to create pods instead of creating raw pods. Once you update env vars in deployment manifest, it'll apply the changes and automatically restart pods in the rolling update method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use deployment instead of pods.

Deployment has [`DeploymentStrategy`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.18/#deploymentstrategy-v1-apps) , [`maxUnavailable`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.18/#rollingupdatedeployment-v1-apps), [maxSurge](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.18/#rollingupdatedeployment-v1-apps) using which you can achieve zero downtime upgrade.

For changing env just change it the deployment yaml and apply it to the cluster. It will rollout the deployment without any downtime.

Kubectl internally calls rest api exposed by Kubernetes API Server. You could check what rest call being sent by kubectl by increasing the verbosity. Once you know the rest api being called you could call those apis as well.

```
kubectl rollout restart deployment/frontend -v=10
```

Comment: i am not using deployment, just using service with pods, is it better to use deployment;  i get the following error. I tried to do rollout restart on service 
    error: services "service2" restarting is not supported.    .. 
Also how can i override an env variable

Comment: yes deployment is better and rollout restart is only for deployments

Answer (score 4):

If you want to restart all pod attached to a deployment, then you can do that by running

```
$ curl -k --data '{"spec":{"template":{"metadata":{"annotations":{"kubectl.kubrnetes.io/restartedAt":"'"$(date +%Y-%m-%dT%T%z)"'"}}}}}' -XPATCH   -H "Accept: application/json, */*" -H "Content-Type: application/strategic-merge-patch+json" localhost:8001/apis/extensions/v1beta1/namespaces/default/deployments/mydeployment
```

Comment: wow, where can i find more docs for this .. is there some typo in cmd .. template or kubrnetes.

Comment: yeah. updated answer.I ran rollout command with `--v=10` flag and notices the logs

Comment: you can check here also https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.18/#rollingupdatedeployment-v1-apps